# Docker: Why are my RestAPI and webAPP not communicating?

Tags: docker, networking, containers

Both Application are running on Docker Container

When I received this error, I decide investigate:

```
App listening at http://localhost:3000
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to http://localhost:5000/auth failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:428:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Running `docker inspect app1||app2` (*command fictitious*), both container aren't not in same bridge. I tried to create add network argument in docker run...

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --network=bridge --name app1 nodejs
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --network=bridge --name app2 python
```

I tried to `--link` too:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --link=app2 --name app1 nodejs
```

But none of them worked. Is there any way too create this network between my application? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

First, don't use `--link`. It only works on the default bridge network, it's fragile, and it's deprecated.

Second, `localhost` refers to "this container". Since your apps are running in two different containers  you're not going to be able to reach your services at `localhost`.

What you want to do is first create a new user-defined network:

```
docker network create mynetwork
```

Launch your containers in that network:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --network=mynetwork --name app1 nodejs
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --network=mynetwork --name app2 python
```

With these two changes, your containers can refer to each other by name: inside your container `app1` you can connect to `http://app2:5000`, and in container `app2` you can connect to `http://app1:3000` (well, assuming that both are presenting http services).

---

What you *really* want to do is start using `docker-compose` instead of doing this all by hand. Docker-compose will set up a user defined network for you automatically, and saves you from having to type long `docker run` command lines.

Comment: I'm still receiving `(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to http://localhost:5000/auth failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0                                                     .0.1:5000` can you help me?

Comment: It looks as if you're still referring to `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`). The opening premise of this answer is that you shouldn't do that.

Comment: All my fetchs are referring to localhost+port, is it wrong?

Comment: That is wrong, yes. Please closely read the answer I've given you which explains (a) why that is wrong and (b) how you can resolve the issue.